# Признак busy для асинхронных вызовов

Tags: php, ajax

Пишу long action контроллер. В JavaScript при помощи setInterval раз в секунду запускается php скрипт, который производит некоторые действия. Время работы этого скрипта 1-3 секунды, после завершения должен сработать следующий шаг. Я хочу предотвратить одновременный запуск двух экземпляров скрипта.

Я пытался записать параметр busy в сессию, а потом считать. Не получилось. Всегда получаю одно и то же из кеша.

После этого я решил сохранять файлик в определенном месте и потом проверять его наличие. Если файлик есть, то скрипт занят, если удален, то свободен. Работа этого скрипта не предполагает многопользовательское использование, поэтому такой вариант вполне прокатил бы, если бы снова не вылезло кеширование.

Пробовал перед проверкой file_exist() запускать clearstatcache() или даже clearstatcache(true, $temp_file). Не помогло. Теперь вот даже не знаю что делать. Вроде бы простенькая задачка, а вот так в лоб не решается.

Comment: вы можете блокировать файл http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php

Comment: по-моему это вопрос как разобраться в настройках кэширования в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: да сделайте хвостовую рекурсию вместо интервала